# Al crear un binding event no me ejecuta nada el evento creado con Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Actualmente tengo un problema al hacer un binding de mi evento clic en mi boton.

Codigo Html5

```
<button (click)="guardar()" >Guardar</button>
```

Codigo .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie',
  templateUrl: './pie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie.component.css']
})
export class PieComponent implements OnInit {

  guardar(){
    console.log("Hola");
      }

  isActive=true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Al dar clic en el boton no me sale nada en la consola de mi navegador y cuando inspecciono el elemento me sale lo siguiente:

```
<button _ngcontent-aka-c18="">Guardar</button>
```

Comment: ¿Hay algún error en la consola?

Comment: @Lobos no marca ningun error, salvo una advertencia que dice "[WDS] Disconnected!"

Comment: `WDS Disconnected`, estas seguro que tu proyecto esta corriendo?.